# Finding solutions of a complicated equation

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following setup

```
Clear["Global`*"];

r1 = Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x + m - 1)^2 + y^2];

w = Sqrt[1 - e]/(1 + e);
V = ((1 - a)*(1 - m))/r1 + (m*r2)/(r2^2 + e) + w^2/2*(x^2 + y^2);

Vx = D[V, x];
Vx0 = Vx /. {y -> 0};
```

Now, the equation `Vx0 == 0` has either 1, 3 or 5 solutions, depending on the particular values of the free parameters $m$, $a$ and $e$. Note that $m \in (0,0.5]$, $a \in [0,0.1]$ and $e \in [0, 0.1]$.

My question is the following: for a given value of $m$, let's say $m = 0.3$, is there an elegant way to find for which values of $a$ and $e$ we have 1, 3 or 5 solutions? Moreover, can we obtain analytical equations giving the $x$ coordinates of the solutions?

Note: I have already found the above using numerical methods (e.g., `FindRoot` etc). My aim now is to seek whether Mathematica can provide analtical equations, regarding the solutions of `Vx0`.

Comment: `Vx0` is not an equation.  Do you mean `Vx0 ==0`? Are we solving for `x`?

Comment: @mikado Yes you are absolutely right, I mena `Vx0 == 0`.

Comment: Those parameters will have some relation with zero set deliminating where solution counts change. It might be a fairly ghastly description.